# Sum Total of Distinct Items In Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, group-by, sum

I have a table of transactions. One column is for the vendor ID, and one column is for the amount due. [There are other columns, but they aren't relevant]

```
id | amount | custid
23 | -31.32 | 904424
24 | -19.94 | 646744
25 | -4.77  | 904424
26 | -29.40 | 972979
```

I want to run a query that delivers the total for each distinct customer ID.
The goal is to determine how much each customer is owed.

Comment: Have you tried an aggregate (GROUP BY) query? Or build a report that uses Sorting & Grouping features with aggregate calc in group footer. Report allows display of detail records as well as summary calcs. You say one column is for vendor ID but I don't see that in example - you show customer ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basic aggregation:

```
select custid, sum(amount) total_amount
from mytable
group by custid
```